# .Include in following query does not include really

Tags: entity-framework, include

```
var diaryEntries = (from entry in repository.GetQuery<OnlineDiary.Internal.Model.DiaryEntry>()
                               .Include("DiaryEntryGradeChangeLog")
                               .Include("DiaryEntryAction")
                                           join diary in repository.GetQuery<OnlineDiary.Internal.Model.OnlineDiary>()                                           
                                           on entry.DiaryId equals diary.Id
                                           group entry
                                           by diary
                                           into diaryEntriesGroup
                                           select new { Diary = diaryEntriesGroup.Key,
                                               DiaryEntry = diaryEntriesGroup.OrderByDescending(diaryEntry => diaryEntry.DateModified).FirstOrDefault(),
                                           });
```

This query does not include "DiaryEntryGradeChangeLog" and "DiaryEntryAction" navigation properties, what is wrong in this query?

I have removed join from the query and corrected as per below, and still it populates nothing

```
var diaryEntries = from entry in repository.GetQuery<OnlineDiary.Internal.Model.DiaryEntry>()
                                   .Include("DiaryEntryGradeChangeLog").Include("DiaryEntryAction")
                                   .Where(e => 1 == 1)
                                       group entry
                                       by entry.OnlineDiary
                                       into diaryEntryGroups
                                       select 
                                       new { DiaryEntry = diaryEntryGroups.OrderByDescending(diaryEntry => diaryEntry.DateModified).FirstOrDefault() };
```

Comment: it simply says they are null, even if I can see them properly in database.

Comment: To clarify, by "populates nothing" do you mean `diaryEntries` is null? or is an `IQueryable` with no items? or is populated with the correct number of objects which have null properties?

Comment: diaryEntries is getting populated with a collection of DiaryEntry which is fine... the "DiaryEntryGradeChangeLog" collection, and "DiaryEntryAction" navigation properties are null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not. `Include` works only if the shape of the query does not change (by design). If you use this query it will work because the shape of the query is still same (`OnlineDiary.Internal.Model.DiaryEntry`):

```
var diaryEntries = (from entry in repository.GetQuery<OnlineDiary.Internal.Model.DiaryEntry>()
                           .Include("DiaryEntryGradeChangeLog")
                           .Include("DiaryEntryAction");
```

But once you use manual join, grouping or projection (`select new { }`) you have changed the shape of the query and all `Include` calls are skipped.

Edit:

You must use something like this (untested) to get related data:

```
var diaryEntries = from entry in repository.GetQuery<OnlineDiary.Internal.Model.DiaryEntry>()
                   group entry by entry.OnlineDiary into diaryEntryGroups
                   let data = diaryEntryGroups.OrderByDescending(diaryEntry => diaryEntry.DateModified).FirstOrDefault()
                   select new { 
                       DiaryEntry = data,
                       GradeChangeLog = data.DiaryEntryGradeChangeLog,
                       Action = data.DiaryEntryAction
                   };
```

or any similar query where you manually populate property for relation in projection to anonymous or unmapped type.

Comment: So you cannot use `Include` and you must use either more complex projection which will load related data or load related data by separate queries.

Comment: The join is causing the problem but the select should be okay as it's applied after the structure has been calculated?

Comment: please see the edited version of question, I have placed in revised query, and still it populates nothing

Comment: You are still using grouping and projection. You cannot use Include in such query.

Comment: I'm interested that the way this works is "by design"- what could the rational have possibly been behind this decision?

Comment: Any source for the definition of "Shape" of the query?