# Network error when using .Include() method on my DbContext

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So, I have been developing a WEB API application with Angular on the frontend. 
I have a method for retrieving matches from the database:

```
[HttpGet("bySportByDateDifference/{sportID:int}/{dateDifferenceNumber:int}")]
    public IEnumerable<Match> GetMatchesBySporByDateDifference([FromRoute] int sportID, [FromRoute] int dateDifferenceNumber)
    {
        IQueryable<Match> matches = Enumerable.Empty<Match>().AsQueryable();

        switch (sportID)
        {
            case 1:
                matches = _context.Matches
                    .Include(m => m.Sport)
                    .Where(m => m.Date.ToLocalTime().Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(dateDifferenceNumber).Date
                                && m.SportID == sportID);
                break;

            case 2:
                matches = _context.Matches
                    .Include(m => m.BasketballMatchComponents)
                    .Where(m => m.Date.ToLocalTime().Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(dateDifferenceNumber).Date
                                && m.SportID == sportID);
                break;

            case 5:
                matches = _context.Matches
                    .Include(m => m.IceHockeyMatchComponents)
                    .Where(m => m.Date.ToLocalTime().Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date.AddDays(dateDifferenceNumber).Date
                                && m.SportID == sportID);
                break;
        }

        return matches;
    }
```

The problem I have encountered is that navigation properties are null in response.

Here is my Match model class:

```
public class Match
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Match date.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date has to be selected!")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sport ID for the particular match.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("Sport")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Sport has to be selected!")]
    public int SportID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Competition ID for the particular match.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("Competition")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Competition has to be selected!")]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Competition has to be selected!")]
    public int CompetitionID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the home team.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("HomeTeam")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Home team has to be selected!")]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Home team has to be selected!")]
    public int HomeTeamID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// ID of the away team.
    /// </summary>
    [ForeignKey("AwayTeam")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Away team has to be selected!")]
    [Range(1, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Away team has to be selected!")]
    public int AwayTeamID { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Home team of the match.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Team HomeTeam { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Away team of the match.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Team AwayTeam { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sport the match belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Sport Sport { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Competition the match belongs to.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual Competition Competition { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Components of a football match.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual FootballMatchComponents FootballMatchComponents { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Components of a basketball match.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual BasketballMatchComponents BasketballMatchComponents { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Components of an ice hockey match.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IceHockeyMatchComponents IceHockeyMatchComponents { get; set; }
}
```

I tried adding .Include() to the query, but this leads to network error when the application calls the method:

> net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

I'm not sure what could be causing this.

### EDIT

I found a solution for this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#related-data-and-serialization

As mentioned in the article, I had to configure Json.NET to ignore cycles that it finds in the object graph.

Comment: So, it's a bit difficult to understand your problem because you show us code with an `Include()` and say it returns `null` for the navigation properties. But then you go on by saying adding Include causes an error and the whole query doesn't work?

Comment: Try adding `.ToList` to your return statement.

Comment: I meant to say that without adding .Include() network error does not happen, but also it doesn't return the navigation properties. When I add .Include() I get the network error.
Unfortunately .ToList didn't solve the problem either :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the shape of your query is changing. Not sure what you are doing with the result. If you add .ToList(), that might fix your issue.

Or you can do .Select(x=>x.Matches).Include .... after the where clause. But again if you change the shape of the query your include will get ignored so if you are doing something with the result after this then adding a .ToList() will become necessary.

Have a look at this SO post, I think you have the same problem:
[IQueryable<T>.Include() gets ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268401/iqueryablet-include-gets-ignored/22272357#22272357)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, adding .Select() did it. But is this really the only way to fix it? For each property I want to retrieve, I have to add it to the Select statement? Is there any other way to avoid this?

Comment: What you are doing should work as is but In your case, seems like there is something that you are doing with the resulting Enumerable thats causing it to ignore your include. So you’ll have to look at it and figure the best way to address this either in the consumer or here. Adding select is just ensuring that portion of that query gets materialized before you do anything else. If you think you are not changing the query shape in the consumer, then try switching the order of where and include in your current code.  Check this to dig deeper: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/7424

Comment: I found a solution for this and now it works as it is supposed to work.
I edited the question and provided a documentation article that helped me fix this.
I accepted your answer because it led me to solution. Thanks once again!