# IQueryable Count() method issue with Inner Join created by .Include() related entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inner-join, iqueryable

```
IQueryable<EntityOne> query = entities.EntityOne
    .Include(t => t.EntityRelated1)
    .Include(t => t.EntityRelated2)
    .AsQueryable();
```

The query generated in "query" variable :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [IdEntityOne], 
 ...
[Extent2].[Id] AS [IdEntityRelatedOne], 
...
[Extent3].[Id] AS [IdEntityRelatedTwo], 
...
FROM   [dbo].[EntityOne] AS [Extent1]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityRelatedOne] AS [Extent2]
       ON [Extent1].[IdRelatedOne] = [Extent2].[Id]
   INNER JOIN [dbo].[EntityRelatedTwo] AS [Extent3]
       ON [Extent1].[IdRelatedTwo] = [Extent3].[Id]
```

After that, on C# code those are the result of counting:

```
var wrongCount = query.Count(); // Returns 295
var correctCount = query.AsEnumerable().Count(); // Returns 10
```

The 295 count is the full EntityOne set numbers of registers. (wrong)

The 10 Count is the desired count after Inner Join.

It sounds like the `IQueryable.Count()` is counting before executing the `InnerJoin` on database. I don't want to generate the `IEnumerable` since I hope the count to be executed on `Sql Server` together with the inner join.

**UPDATE 1**

Trying to manually execute the inner join:

```
IQueryable<EntityOne> query2 = entities.EntityOne.Join(entities.EntityTwo,
     eone=> eone.IdRelatedOne, en => en.Id,
     (x, y) => x);
```

The SQL code generated in "query2" is :

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
...
FROM [dbo].[EntityOne] AS [Extent1]
```

As you can see, the related entity is not included on Inner Join forced by linq Join statement.

**Update 2**

I dont know if it matters but, the IdEntityRelated1 on EntityOne is a required property, plus its not a foreign key on database, just a Integer field that stores the Id of the related entity. (Im working with POCO classes with Database First)

I have another working sources where fields but they're nullable integers instead of required. Maybe should I not try to do an Include to force Inner Join between required relationships?

Comment: A good starting point could be the SQL Server profiler so you see exactly the query runned on SQL Server. If the result that you need is the EntityOne that has a not null RelatedEntity you could just check it. Could be that EF eager loading has not been designed to allow count.

Comment: @bubi I tried to force the Join, as you can see on Update 1 section in my post, but it's not generating the inner join to related entities...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a required association, but the expected objects are not present in the database.

But let's first see what EF does.

In the **first count**...

```
var wrongCount = query.Count();
```

...the `Include`s are ignored. There's no reason to execute them because EF has been told that the referred objects (`EntityRelated1` and `EntityRelated2` are mandatory, so inner joins *are expected to find the related records*. If they do, EF figures it may as well just count `entities.EntityOne` and skip the rest. The `Includes` are only going to make the query more expensive and they don't affect the result.

You can check that by monitoring the SQL that's executed for the count. That's not the SQL generated when you look at `query` only! It's probably something that simply boils down to

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[EntityOne]
```

So the first count returns a correct count of all `EntityOne` records in the database.

For the **second count** you force execution of the entire query that's stored in the `query` variable, the SQL statement that you show. Then you count its results in memory – and it returns `10`. This means that the query with the inner joins does actually return 10 records. That, in turn, can only mean one thing: there are 285 `EntityOne.IdRelatedOne` values that don't point to an existing `EntityRelatedOne` record. But you mapped the association as required, so EF generates an inner join. An outer join would also return 295.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I've checked the database and you're right, the related data is missing in some registers, I've changed my query to check the related data manually.

Answer (score 0):

`Include` is not a LINQ method proper, is an EntityFramework extension designed to do eager loading and not much else. `Include`s [are lost if the query shape changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236(v=vs.103).aspx):

> When you call the Include method, the query path is only valid on the returned instance of the IQueryable of T. Other instances of IQueryable of T and the context itself are not affected.

Specifically this means that, for instance aggregates on top of the `Include`d `IQueryable<T>` are going to loose the `Include` (which is exactly what you see).

See [Tip 22 - How to make Include really Include](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx), [IQueryable.Include() gets ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22268401/iqueryablet-include-gets-ignored), [Include in following query does not include really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232481/include-in-following-query-does-not-include-really) and many more.

Comment: @Remus_Rusanu I forced the Inner Join with linq "Join" statement. Its not including the related entities, as you can see on Update 1